# Easier way to create an auxiliary table

Tags: sql, database, google-sheets, data-entry

I am working with a long database of service providers listed in a table having all the locations in other table. I always work in a very manual way but I wanted to know if you have some good practices or even tricks or techniques to create this intermediate table.

I will probably just match the IDs manually in the new table, using Google sheets, selecting the first providers ID and then typing the locations ID. Is there a better way to improve it? Mainly to avoid changing between tabs so many times.

| Provider ID | Provider |
| --- | --- |
| Prov Id 1 | Provider 1 |
| Prov Id 2 | Provider 2 |

| Location ID | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Loc Id 1 | Location 1 |
| Loc Id 2 | Location 2 |

| Provider ID | Location ID |
| --- | --- |
| Prov Id 1 | Location 1 |
| Prov Id 1 | Location 2 |
| Prov Id 1 | Location 3 |

Comment: Which tables are your input and which one output? I don't see any relation between first two table.

Comment: this is where some user interfaces get written.  is there an application that manages this data?  there are many ways to represent relationships in a UI.

Comment: @Harun24hr the relationship is the third table that matches providers and locations

Comment: @Randy there is no app here sadly, just plain google sheets with data from various sources (then power bi and python to use it)